# Misalignment of Preloader on iPhones

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, web-testing

I have the following preloader:

```css
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Preloader
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat+Alternates:wght@500;700&family=Montserrat:wght@400;600&family=Oswald:wght@500&family=Pacifico&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,900;1,500&display=swap');
.svg-file {
  width: 40vw;
  max-width: 133px;
}

.svg-file path {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke: rgb(1, 36, 133);
}

.svg-file.z-logo path {
  stroke-dasharray: 550;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

.svg-file.z-logo path {
  animation: animate-zlogo 2s linear infinite;
}

.svg-file.z-logo svg {
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
  transform: scale(2);
}

.svg-file h2 {
  font-family: "Roboto", cursive;
  transform: translate(0, 50px) skewX(-210deg) rotate(-6deg);
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #044d77;
}

.svg-file span {
  animation: dots 2.5s steps(6, end) infinite;
  font-size: 5em;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(0, 65px) skewX(-210deg) rotate(-6deg);
  background-color: rgb(5, 46, 80);
  width: 8px;
  height: 5px;
}

@keyframes fadein-fadeout {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes animate-zlogo {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -50;
  }
  20% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 550;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  40% {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
  }
  60% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
    fill: #05f7f9;
  }
  80% {
    stroke-width: 0;
    fill: #05f7f9;
  }
  100% {
    /* stroke-dashoffset: 0; */
    stroke-width: 3;
    fill: transparent;
  }
}

#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.z-logo svg {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

.z-logo::before {
  content: "";
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 60vw;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 60vw;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Preloader -->
<div id="preloader">
  <div class="svg-file z-logo">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 133 133" width="133" height="133">
        <g id="H">
          <path
            d="M45.33 78.22L87.67 78.22L87.67 133L121.05 133L121.05 0L87.67 0L87.67 49.33L45.33 49.33L45.33 0L11.95 0L11.95 133L45.33 133L45.33 78.22Z"
            fill="#47AF9A" />
        </g>
      </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

This seems to work fine on Android devices such as Samsung phones...etc. However, for some reason, the width of the letter "H" gets misaligned on iPhone devices such as iPhone 14, as shown below:

[image]

I have included the Meta tag and tried every solution such as modifying the `.svg-file.z-logo` class and adding these properties:

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
```

This still does not fix the issue. Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `text-align: center;` to `.svg-file`.

You can also fix on IOS by removing `transform: scale(2);` on `.svg-file.z-logo svg` and by removing the `width: 50%;` on `.z-logo svg`

Comment: adding `text-align` solves it, but is it guaranteed to work on all ios devices? or should I opt for another solution removing `transform: scale(2);`?

Comment: It's guaranteed to work on all IOS devices with `text-align`.